# How to set a favicon for Doxygen output

Tags: doxygen, favicon

I am automating documentation generation using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org).  How can I specify a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) (URL icon) for the output?

Comment: Not really an answer. As far as I know there is no way to do this at the moment. I looked at he wiki page and saw that the method <link rel="shortcut icon" href="myicon.ico" /> should work so incorporated it in a test page. It worked for Firefox and OPera but not for IE9 and Google Chrome. Any ideas how it could work there?

Comment: Did you add that manually to the output from Doxygen, or did you find a way to have Doxygen output that tag automatically?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In doxygen one has the possibility to define his own HTML header file, best based on the default HTML header file.

To obtain the default HTML header file, syntax:

```
doxygen -w html headerFile footerFile styleSheetFile [configFile]
```

in the headerFile insert in the head part a line like:

```
<link rel="icon" href="$relpath^my_icon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Note: that the `$relpath^` part is necessary especially in case of `CREATE_SUBDIRS` is set.

Furthermore in the configuration file (Doxyfile) you have to set:

```
HTML_HEADER            = headerFile
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       += my_icon.ico
```

Of course the standard restrictions regarding favicons still apply (regarding support by browsers etc.).