Link logo back to main website from within doxygen
In doxygen how can you link the logo back to your main site.
For example, if doxygen is in
sandbox.mywebsite.com how do I set the logo so that clicking on it takes the user to mywebsite.com
reading doxygen documentation and trying different wizard options

Which version of doxygen are you using? What did you try (please show an example. Probably you should use the <img> or \image command with full path to the logo.

Maybe you should also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215463/how-to-set-a-favicon-for-doxygen-output
